# How do I convert complex to exponential form?

Tags: calculus

How to convert: $470\left(\sqrt{1-3.078i} \right) $ to exponential form. I tried, but I cant get the correct solution.

I got angle $72$ and $r=714913,9$,

I should get result $847,6\cdot e^{-36}$.

Comment: Start by writing the expression inside the square root using polar coordinates, then taking the root will be easy.
PS: who invents exercises like these? I find them complete nonsense.

Comment: You should get 36 in degrees

Comment: And rather 8476 it should be 845.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Notice, when $z\in\mathbb{C}$:
>
> $$z=\Re[z]+\Im[z]i=|z|e^{\arg(z)i}=|z|\cos(\arg(z))+|z|\sin(\arg(z))i$$
>
> Where $|z|=\sqrt{\Re^2[z]+\Im^2[z]}$.

So, when $z\in\mathbb{C}$:

$$x\sqrt{z}=x\sqrt{|z|e^{\arg(z)i}}=x\cdot\sqrt{|z|}\cdot\sqrt{e^{\arg(z)i}}=x\sqrt{|z|}e^{\frac{\arg(z)i}{2}}$$

---

In your example, you get:

$$470\sqrt{1-3.078i}=470\sqrt{\sqrt{1^2+3.078^2}}e^{-\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{3.078}{1}\right)i}{2}}$$

**EDIT:**

To find the argument use [this](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/1a6db59b906401c38a631b3049fce54d5672333f) or think about a complex number that has a positive real part ($x$) and a negative imaginary part ($y$), then:

$$\arg(x-yi)=-\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$

Comment: Could you show how you calculate $\arg{z}$?

Comment: Yes, Look to my edit

Answer (score 1):

Let's explore this problem:
Start with what exponential format is:
$$a+ib = r e^{i \theta}$$
From here we can derive $r$ and $\theta$:
$$ r = (a+ib)(a+ib)^* $$
and 
$$ \theta = \arctan{b/a} = \arctan{\frac{(a+bi)-(a+bi)^*}{i(a+bi)+i(a+bi)^*}}$$
Plugging your numbers in I get:

> $$r = \sqrt{470(\sqrt{1-3.078i})(470(\sqrt{1-3.078i})^*}=\sqrt{470^2 \sqrt{1+3.078^2}}$$
>  $$\theta = \arctan{\frac{\sqrt{1-3.078i}-\sqrt{1+3.078i}}{i(\sqrt{1-3.078i}+\sqrt{1+3.078i})}} = -36^o$$

Answer (score 0):

convert $\sqrt{1-3.078 i}$ to polar.

$\tan\theta = -3.078 = 72$ degrees. (well very nearly) $= -\frac {2\pi}{5}$ radians.

$r = \sqrt {1+3.078^2} = 3.23$

$470 \sqrt {3.23 e^{-\frac {2\pi i}{5}}} = 845.5 e^{-\frac {\pi i}5}$

If you haven't learned exponential notation for complex numbers, you could say.

$470 (3.23 (\cos -72 + i \sin -72))^{\frac 12} = 845.5 (\cos -36 + i \sin -36)$

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to first square the expression. In general, for $z= a + i b$ for the $lhs$ multiply and divide by $a^2+b^2$, which is just $1$ so you havn't changed anything, then $z = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} + i \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$.

The reason for this is that you can now write $\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} = \cos \theta, \,\,\, \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} = \sin \theta$ (you can check that $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta = 1$). This gives $z = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} (\cos \theta + i \sin \theta) \equiv r e^{i \theta}$ (using de Moirve's Theorem and where you should be able to identify $r$).

Once you have $a + i b$ in polar form, then take the square root, which gives $\sqrt{z} = \sqrt{r} e^{i \theta/2}$.